# How to design a responsive tweet style using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a new developer and I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 to design a responsive tweet style that I need to use for styling a list of tweets. 
The style should be responsive and look like the following image:
[image]

I am still struggling in designing it similar to what shown in the image above. So could you please tell me how I can make it responsive and similar to the prototype shown in the image.

Here's a snippet of my code, which you can view it [here in Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/techLover/GqWt0RDc42):

```
<div class="continaer">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="twitter-container">
      <div class="col-sm-12 pull-right">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input value="" type="checkbox">Select</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input value="" type="checkbox">Saved</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="profileImage img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
      <a href="\&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;" target="_blank">
        @tweet.Name
      </a>
      <span class="username">ScreenName</span>
      <div class="date">Creation Date</div>
      <div class="tweetTxt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
        Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et ma
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <span class="label label-primary">Tag #1</span>
          <span class="label label-primary">Tag #2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 pull -right">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input value="" type="checkbox">Retweeted</label>
          </div>
          <span class="label label-success">Retweet Count</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>            
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read about the bootstrap Grids

Comment: @RaviUbana, thanks for your help. I already read about it. As I said, I am a new user of Bootstrap and I am struggling with it as I have to create a custom style in addition to the base bootstrap style.